# Print message when result is not returned

Tags: java

I want to log error message when there is no result. I removed the part which throws exception into the lambda expression but now I get error `Error:(148,83) java: 'void' type not allowed here`

```
if(.....){
    return currentInteractions.get().stream().filter(.....)
            .findFirst().orElseThrow( () -> log.debug("Instance {} not waiting for response", nodeInstanceId));
}
```

Do you know in this case how I can log message when `findFirst` does not return result?

Comment: What do you want the code to do *after* you've logged that message? Throw an exception? Return `null`? Something else? The compiler is telling you that because you called `orElseThrow()`, the lambdas expression must return an exception object, and you're not returning anything.

Comment: I need just to log that message like this:`.findFirst().orElse(log.debug("Instance {} not waiting for response", nodeInstanceId));`

Comment: And then what should happen in the code? What will the caller of the method containing that code see next? Does the method return with some value *(and which value would that be?)*, or does the method throw an exception *(and which exception would that be?)*. Those are really the only two choices.

Comment: nothing. null object for currentInteractions should be returned.

Comment: Then why are you calling `orElseThrow()`, if you're not going to throw an exception? --- You should be calling `orElseGet(() -> { log("boo"); return null; })`

Comment: *FYI:* `null` is not "nothing", it is an actual value.

Answer (score 1):

You can log inside orElseThrow but also return an new exception as below inside curly braces.

```
if(.....){
    return currentInteractions.get().stream().filter(.....)
            .findFirst().orElseThrow(() -> 
              { 
                log.debug("Instance {} not waiting for response", nodeInstanceId);
                // if no exception has to be thrown return null
                return new Exception();
              }
             );
    }
```

If you don't have any exception please use `orElseGet` instead of `orElseThrow` as  @Andreas suggested.

Comment: Is it possible just to log message without Throw?

Comment: @PeterPenzov Yes, use `orElseGet()` and `return null;` --- Laminoo, see [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60618780/print-message-when-result-is-not-returned?noredirect=1#comment107245908_60618780) for why that is so.